# how to change the pixel color in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to change the pixel color of an image in this way.

```
im = imread('example.jpg');

im1 = im(:,:,1);
im2 = im(:,:,2);
im3 = im(:,:,3);

im1(1,1) = 255;
im2(1,1) = 255;
im3(1,1) = 255;

im = cat(3,im1,im2,im3);
```

Is it a right way to do this?

As this code don't change the pixel color.

```
p = impixel(im, 1,1);
```

p is not equal to [255 255 255]

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it works, got [255 255 255] whereas original one was [226 137 125]..

Your approach works but it could be done by shorter process like this:

```
im          = imread('example.jpg');
im(1, 1, :) = [255 255 255];
p           = [im(1, 1, :)];
```

Comment: Did you try the `impixel` part? That doesn't look right. But I agree with your improved version; splitting the image doesn't achieve anything useful.

Comment: @beaker - Yess I tried it and it worked too.. Actually I hadn' t known about "impixel" function but I just wrote it, and resulted "255   255   255". The code above, doesn' t give anthing wrong to me, indeed..

Comment: I hadn't heard of it either, but looking at the documentation it looks like `c` and `r` should be vectors, so I didn't know if it would throw an error if you used scalars. Apparently it doesn't :)

Comment: @beaker - No, it doesn' t give error at all. "c" and "r" refers to selected columns and rows and it allows us to enter 1x1 vector {  suppose it is an alternative way to call scalar (:  } or bigger dim vector, I think. Thus, I suppose OP' s usage is not wrong..